# is there a good place to discuss compilers?

Tags: compiler-construction, language-features, language-design

I am looking for some place where I can discus compilers and language design ? forum or any thing of this sort

Comment: Are there special things you want to discuss (rather than asking for how to do things), so that SO is not enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Lambda The Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/) is a website which seems to be the favourite hang-out for many language designers.

Answer (score 3):

The usenet group comp.compilers is available for that sort of thing. It seems to be less active now than it used to be.

If you're interested in optimization and code generation, the LLVM IRC channel has many knowledgeable and helpful people. (llvm.org).

Comment: ...probably because most ISPs are dropping usenet support these days.